# How To Use Javascript to mimic a html link with id attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a javascript function that mimics the following code:

```
<a href="#" id="g3cm_btn"><b>Place Holder Text</b></a>
```

The id="g3cm_btn" is somehow triggering an event in an attached js file.

I have created a form with only one field where the phone number is asked.  Once the phone number is asked, I want the submit button to trigger a javascript function that acts just like someone clicked on the place holder text link from above.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form1" onSubmit="">
<input id="phone" type="tel" value="" size="19" required placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="phone"><br>
<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Call Me Now" name="Submit" onClick="reply_click()">
</form>

<script>
function reply_click()
{
    window.location.href = '#';
    document.getElementById('g3cm_btn');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create this "g3cm_btn" element when the button is clicked and insert it in the page somewhere?

Comment: To know which elements are being triggered by that element:

 Press F12 in your chrome browser (i suggest), then right click on the element of your interest and click on Inspect Element. Look the Id and/or classes or events relevant. Now, open the Sources tab, look for the page scripts, and find your element's ID, classes or events there.

Comment: Hi Will,  I believe that the g3cm_btn element exists as a function in a private file.  I am implementing a add-on that I got from a company (with very poor tech support).  All I know is that when I have retrieved the phone number using the phone and then click on the Place Holder Text link, it triggers the add-on.  I just need to trigger the add-on without having to click twice.  (Once on the form and once on the link.)

Comment: Hi celerno, I did as you suggest and it is showing the g2cm_btn as an event listener that is being listened to by jquery.  I am not sure if that helps.